# What's the meaning of this bash parameter expansion syntax?

Tags: bash

In the [golang GOPATH documentation](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH) it instructs you to add the following to your bash PATH:

```
${GOPATH//://bin:}/bin
```

What does the `//://bin:` mean here?

`$GOPATH` appears to evaluate to the same value as `${GOPATH//://bin:}`

My first guess was that this somehow expands into all subdirectories of `$GOPATH` that have a `/bin` subdirectory, but this does not appear to be the case. I added some subdirectories to my $GOPATH with a `/bin` dir, and the above expression does not include them.

I dug into my manpage for bash and didn't see any hints.

Comment: It is replacing every occurrence of `:` with `/bin:`

Answer (score 0):

`man bash` says under PARAMETER EXPANSION:

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce  a  pattern  just  as  in
>                 pathname expansion.  Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against
>                 its value is replaced with string.  If pattern begins with /, all matches  of  pattern are replaced with string.  Normally only the first match is replaced.

e.g.

```
$ GOPATH=a:b:c
$ echo ${GOPATH//://bin:}
a/bin:b/bin:c
```

Comment: Got it, we're substituting every instance of `:` in `$GOPATH/` with `/bin:` and then (in my very first example) adding `/bin` to the last one that didn't have a `:` after it. I'm very surprised that bash can parse this unambiguously. What's the logic that drives the second and third `/` to delimit the pattern substitution and not the first and fourth?

Comment: @OregonTrail The first delimiter is either `/` or `//`. There's no ambiguity because the pattern can't be empty (what would that mean?). The second delimiter is always the next `/`. It can be followed by anything, so the `/` at the beginning of the replacement is not a problem.

Comment: @OregonTrail If the pattern contains `/` you can escape it as `\/`